# Polymer 1.0: Help to avoid all elements making same ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

My scenario: I have multiple elements that all look like this

```
<dom-module is="elm1">
    <iron-ajax id="ajax"></iron-ajax>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "elm1",

        properties: {
            token: {
                type: String,
                observer: "_tokenChanged"
            } 
        },

        _tokenChanged: function() {
            this.$.ajax.url = "someUrl" + this.token;
            this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now imagine I have say 10 of these on the page.

```
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
<elm1 token="123456"></elm1>
```

That's 10 seperate calls to the exact same endpoint that needs to take place. How can I consolidate it down to just one request that can then be shared between elements?

My problem is I have too many elements making too many of the same ajax calls to get the exact same data. It's hurting our performance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, include an [`iron-meta`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta) element containing the results of the AJAX call. In your `tokenChanged` function, check the contents of the `iron-meta` before firing the AJAX request. If the data is there, use it, if not check a second `iron-meta` element to see if it contains an `iron-ajax` Promise. If so, that Promise will return the results of the AJAX request, if not then you can fire your AJAX request and store the resultant Promise in the second `iron-meta` accordingly.

Note that both `iron-meta` keys should incorporate the `token` value, so as to avoid collisions with `elm1` instances using a different value.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for. Anyway you could provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You may try utilizing the auto param of iron-ajax. It will only make the request if the value changes. So in this example, there would be just one request if the token does not change. I like Zikes response to your question, you could do this in the _tokenResponse method.

```html
<dom-module is="elm1">
    <iron-ajax 
     auto
     url={{url}}
     on-response="_tokenResponse"></iron-ajax>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "elm1",
        properties: {
            token:    String,
            url: {
             type:   String,
             computed:  '_url(token)'
            }
        },
        _url: function(token){
         return "someUrl" + token;
        },
        _tokenResponse: function(e, detail) {
            //do something with the response
        }
    });
</script>
```